# Where equals SQL ignoring whitespaces

Tags: php, mysql, sql

When I search for results from my table with the use of WHERE equals Clause I've got results that I would prefer to be different. For instance, when I look for result and my query is
`SELECT * FROM users WHERE login="lapis"` result is the same as it would be in 
`SELECT * FROM users WHERE login="lapis "`. The whitespace at the end is ignored which is problem in my code as I use this query for my php login script and anyone can log into account with proper password but technically without proper login (it should be "lapis", not "lapis "). Is there anything I can do with it?

Comment: `str_replace(' ','',$login_variable)` then pass it to your query string.

Comment: Hard to understand your question sorry! need more details

Comment: Maybe like is what you need 'Per the SQL standard, LIKE performs matching on a per-character basis, thus it can produce results different from the = comparison operator:' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Comment: You could use `LIKE "%lapis %"` if you don't want to ignore trailin whitespaces. Edit: P.Salmon was faster :D

Comment: This is standard sql behavior (I,e. cross database).  There are various ways to work around this, just pick one.  If you don’t care about indexes, just add a '.' at the end before doing the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very detailed, but from what I can gather a simple preg_replace() will do what you want.

For example,

```
$login = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', 'lapis '); // This will output: lapis

$conn->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='".$login."'")
```

preg_replace with the characters I included will remove ALL whitespace, including tabs and other forms.

Answer (score 0):

You can do your query like the following.

```
    SELECT * FROM users WHERE login LIKE "your_input_here"
```

Using `LIKE` solves the problem.

For example:

```
    SELECT * FROM users WHERE login LIKE "lapis"
```

Only will get values that `'lapis'` as login. And

```
    SELECT * FROM users WHERE login LIKE "lapis "
```

Only will get values that `'lapis '` as login.

Answer (score 0):

This removes whitespace from the end in your result.

```sql
SELECT RTRIM(username) FROM users WHERE login="lapis"
```